# Doubts about kyc information request of crypto exchange site

Tags: exchanges, know-your-customer

Is it normal for a crypto exchange market site to require a photo of myself holding a signed handwritten note in one hand and my id card in the other as kyc information? I'm not a hostage and it feels weird. Usually it's enough to just email them a copy of a document.
It's the first time I hear about this. Should I look for a different exchange?

Comment: What exchange are you trying to use?

Comment: @CryptoBitcoin Kraken.com

Comment: Kraken.com is a reputable site, as far as i can tell. I think this practice is forced on them by regulators. However, it's not really a question about Bitcoin itself so i don't think it fits this site. Good luck navigating through all this :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a pretty common onboarding experience with exchanges. You used to only have to upload a photo ID of yourself, however a lot of these databases of users' photo IDs were leaked so now new signup require that you write something down to prove you are not impersonating another individual. As others have pointed out there are ways to get bitcoin without going through all of this.

If you are only looking to buy and sell small amounts (usually less than $2000) of BTC, lots of bitcoin ATM's allow small purchases like this by only providing a phone number. Be prepared to pay a 8-20%+ transaction fee though.

https://coinatmradar.com/bitcoin-atm-map/

Answer (score 0):

> Should I look for a different exchange?

Yes. Do not use KYC exchanges.

https://bisq.network/